# Extra phone icons get displayed in Layout file in Android code

Tags: java, android, xml

I am doing a Android app where I want to show "Travels and Holidays" button in the AppActivity.java and main.xml.
When clicked on it, it goes to App2Activity.java and main2.xml where there is a list of travels like Travels1, Travels2, Travels3, Travels4.
When clicked on any travels, it goes to App3Activity.java and main3.xml where there is a list of numbers of that travels.
Here is the code:

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/travel_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### AppActivity.java

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class AppActivity extends Activity{
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(AppActivity.this, App2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });   
    }
}
```

### App2Activity.java

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class App2Activity extends Activity{
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(App2Activity.this, App3Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("number1","456546546");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });   

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(App2Activity.this, App3Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("number1","546547567");
                i.putExtra("number2","654645654");
                i.putExtra("number3","6456546654");
                i.putExtra("number4","6456546565");
                i.putExtra("number5","876657567");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });  

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(App2Activity.this, App3Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("number1","546575676");
                i.putExtra("number2","65244288820");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });       

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(App2Activity.this, App3Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("number1","822442676");
                i.putExtra("number2","442776");
                i.putExtra("number3","91669876");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });  

    }
}
```

### main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/travel1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/travel2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/travel3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/travel4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### App3Activity.java

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class App3Activity extends Activity {
    ImageButton btnPhoneOne, btnPhoneTwo, btnPhoneThree, btnPhoneFour, btnPhoneFive; 
    TextView txtNum1, txtNum2, txtNum3, txtNum4, txtNum5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main3);

        btnPhoneOne = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPhone1);
        btnPhoneTwo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPhone2);
        btnPhoneThree = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPhone3);
        btnPhoneFour = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPhone4);
        btnPhoneFive = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPhone5);

        txtNum1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber1);
        txtNum2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber2);
        txtNum3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber3);
        txtNum4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber4);
        txtNum5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber5);

        String number1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("number1");
        String number2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("number2");
        String number3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("number3");
        String number4 = getIntent().getStringExtra("number4");
        String number5 = getIntent().getStringExtra("number5");

        txtNum1.setText(number1);
        txtNum2.setText(number2);
        txtNum3.setText(number3);
        txtNum4.setText(number4);
        txtNum5.setText(number5);

        btnPhoneOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txtNum1.getText()));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });

        btnPhoneTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txtNum2.getText()));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });

        btnPhoneThree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txtNum3.getText()));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });

        btnPhoneFour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txtNum4.getText()));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });

        btnPhoneFive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txtNum5.getText()));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### main3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContainer1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNumber1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPhone1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContainer2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNumber2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPhone2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContainer3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNumber3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPhone3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContainer4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNumber4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPhone4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContainer5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNumber5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPhone5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Helpline Number</string>
    <string name="travel_button">Travels and Holidays</string>
    <string name="travel1">Travels1</string>
    <string name="travel2">Travels2</string>
    <string name="travel3">Travels3</string>
    <string name="travel4">Travels4</string>

</resources>
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".AppActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".App2Activity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".App3Activity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is even if there is only 2 numbers in any travels, it shows 3 extra phone icons in third activity.

But what I want is how many numbers are there in particular travels, only so many phone icons should be there for each number.

How to fix this? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't cross post: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/284812/139925

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I dont get the proper answer wherever I post. Then what is the use of posting?

Comment: You're probably not getting any answers because you're asking people to sift through a metric crap-tonne of code to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect Phone Number length on respected textview and Set visibility of phone icons See Code:

```
    package com.example.android;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class App3Activity extends Activity {
        ImageButton btnPhoneOne, btnPhoneTwo, btnPhoneThree, btnPhoneFour, btnPhoneFive; 
        TextView txtNum1, txtNum2, txtNum3, txtNum4, txtNum5;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main3);

            btnPhoneOne = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPhone1);
            btnPhoneTwo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPhone2);
            btnPhoneThree = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPhone3);
            btnPhoneFour = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPhone4);
            btnPhoneFive = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPhone5);

            txtNum1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber1);
            txtNum2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber2);
            txtNum3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber3);
            txtNum4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber4);
            txtNum5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber5);

            String number1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("number1");
            String number2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("number2");
            String number3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("number3");
            String number4 = getIntent().getStringExtra("number4");
            String number5 = getIntent().getStringExtra("number5");

            txtNum1.setText(number1);
            txtNum2.setText(number2);
            txtNum3.setText(number3);
            txtNum4.setText(number4);
            txtNum5.setText(number5);

if(txtNum1.getText().toString().length() > 0)
    btnPhoneOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    btnPhoneOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);

if(txtNum2.getText().toString().length() > 0)
    btnPhoneTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    btnPhoneTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

if(txtNum3.getText().toString().length() > 0)
    btnPhoneThree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    btnPhoneThree.setVisibility(View.GONE);

if(txtNum4.getText().toString().length() > 0)
    btnPhoneFour.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    btnPhoneFour.setVisibility(View.GONE);

if(txtNum5.getText().toString().length() > 0)
    btnPhoneFive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    btnPhoneFive.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            btnPhoneOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txtNum1.getText()));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            });

            btnPhoneTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txtNum2.getText()));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            });

            btnPhoneThree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txtNum3.getText()));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            });

            btnPhoneFour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txtNum4.getText()));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            });

            btnPhoneFive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txtNum5.getText()));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

It will help you to remove extra phone icons.